# Disaster Recovery for EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 **Reserved instance** running in one region. what if the region undergoes to **disaster**(either natural or man-made). How do I recovery my instance and data? what do I do for the recovery and will it cost?

I have read some content about RTO and RPO how should I use them?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Region contains of availability zones. Your instance belong to such a zone.
There are ways to recover from zone and region disaster. However please note that region disaster happens very seldom and it covers whole internet usually :-)

**What will be with your service availability in case of a disaster?**
If you have only one EC2 instance running, then it won't be available. We need to add more instances to handle such cases.
AutoScalling group can help to manage required load automatically for you.
Load balancing will balance the load between instances.

**What will be with your data in case of a disaster?**
If you don't replicate it, then it can be lost. However AWS provides replication out of the box between availability zones (AZ). Replication between regions is tricky and will require a special handling.
Please note that usually EC2 doesn't relate to data, it relates to computing resource. Data is stored in file storages (EBS, S3) or DBs(RDS, DynamoDB etc.).
All these services support data replication between AZ out of the box.

There are different strategies to go further. I hope my answer will be useful as the first step to dive there.